# Accessing DefaultScheduleEvent Data object

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

My DefaultScheduleEvent is created as followed:

```
DefaultScheduleEvent newResourceEvent = new DefaultScheduleEvent(reason, dteBeginOrWaitingItem, dteEndOrWaitingItem, orWaitinglist);
```

`orWaitinglist` is an object, which contains values and more objects.

Now how do I access this object in my `JSF`page.

The Primefaces demo shows you can access the event object, as showed below. But how can I put the values of the object `orWaitinglist` inside the `p:inputText`-field.

```
<p:inputText id="title" value="#{scheduleController.event.data}" required="true"/>
```

DefaultScheduleEvent.java

```
public DefaultScheduleEvent(String title, Date start, Date end, Object data) {
    this.title = title;
    this.startDate = start;
    this.endDate = end;
    this.data = data;
}

public Object getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

ScheduleController.java

```
public ScheduleEvent getEvent() {
        return event;
}
public void setEvent(ScheduleEvent event) {
        this.event = event;
}
```

OrWaitinglist.java

```
public OrWaitinglist(BigDecimal WKey, Patients patients, OrBaseLists orBaseListsByWPriority, String WDescription, int WState, Date WDateInserted, Date WDateModified, String WModifiedBy, byte WPlannedType, boolean WCanBeScheduled) {
    this.WKey = WKey;
    this.patients = patients;
    this.orBaseListsByWPriority = orBaseListsByWPriority;
    this.WDescription = WDescription;
    this.WState = WState;
    this.WDateInserted = WDateInserted;
    this.WDateModified = WDateModified;
    this.WModifiedBy = WModifiedBy;
    this.WPlannedType = WPlannedType;
    this.WCanBeScheduled = WCanBeScheduled;
}
```

Comment: Please show your managed bean structure (and the DefaultScheduleEvent basic class structure) to get exact guidance on this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza is this enough? cuz the class is rather huge

Comment: What's the `orWaiting` object you mention in your question? I can't see it nor in your managed bean nor in your `ScheduleEvent` class.

Comment: You should show the `orWaitinglist` class. The `inputText` field requires a string. If your `orWaitinglist` object would have an attribute `name` and a public set and get method you could just add it to the EL like this: `value="#{scheduleController.event.data.name}"`. (Maybe I'm missunderstanding what you are trying to achieve though.

Comment: How's this `orWaiting` object instance related to the managed bean?

Comment: Your `OrWaitinglist` has so many values... Which values do you want to show in the input text? All of them?

Comment: Well i have a few textboxes i want to fill up with data coming from the orWaitinglist object for example <p:inputText id="description" value="#{scheduleController.event.data.description}" >
It is related as in there is the possibility to add an Object to the creation of the DefaultScheduleEvent ...

Comment: @ Jens: yes that is exactly what i'm trying to achieve here, I want to GET the information from this Object, which in my case is an instance of the OrWaitinglist modelclass, that class contains a few String types. The only get/set that is provided is the get/set Data in DefaultScheduleEvent.java

Comment: i fixed it by putting the ID of the waitinglistobject into the object and then write a method that gets the full orwaitinglistobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access you custom object using the standard JSF notation syntax. Just make sure that your object has setters and getters for the fields that need to be accessed. Then you can either pass in, or create a new object to the DefaultScheduleEvent and access it from the presentation layer.

```
DefaultScheduleEvent newResourceEvent = new DefaultScheduleEvent(reason, dteBeginOrWaitingItem, dteEndOrWaitingItem, new OrWaitinglist();
```

*Using a default constructor*

The JSF page can then access this using:

```
<p:inputText value="#{scheduleController.event.data.WKey}"/>
```

**NB. By convention your variables should start with a lowercase letter! (*WKey* is better written *wKey*)**